# What information can I get from the android browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, browser

I know I can get screen width/height in a browser, can I get any other information about the device?  Device name, OS, carrier, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though the only additional resources you're provided with have to do with screen density and resolution: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/index.html.  However, if you are going to display this page in a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), you can utilize the Java-Javascript bridge to access any information available to the standard Java API (or non standard if you want to get creative and use reflection ;-) )

Comment: Thanks!  That's a start... I'm still hoping I can get some more info.  And I'd love to be able to use a WebView, but I don't want to force users to download apps just to browse web pages.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: Oops, didn't see you meant from the browser javascript >< disregard information below.

`android.os.Build` provides a lot of information.
Try:

```
String s="Debug-infos:";
s += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
s += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK;
s += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
s += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";
```